# A problem with overloading an action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

how should look the Global.asax file and my Controller's action to process 2 types of the URL:

```
http://.../Search
http://.../Search?q=abc&p=1&...&...&...& (many parameters, do I have to list all 
                                          of them in the Global.asax file ?)
```

?

Comment: there are many other questions about this on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to list them all in your global.asax file, just have them as optional parameters in your action.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Search(string q, int page = 1, string country = "", etc etc)
```

If you're not able to use default values, just make them nullable.

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Search(string q, int? page, string country, etc etc)
```

Savvy?

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: but the problem is, I get the error `The current request for action 'Search' on controller type '' is ambiguous between the following action methods:` and here is the list of that 2 methods

Comment: @Tony: If you make your parameters optional, you should be able to combine your actions into a single action, eliminating any ambiguity.

Comment: what Charlino is saying is that you do not need foo(int a, int b) and foo(int a) all you need is foo(int a,int? b)

Comment: Echo what @Andrey said. The above technique should enable you to have just one action method to rule them all.